# Does a synthesist risk exploding upon entering the Positive Energy Plane?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, planes, summoner

A [summoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/) that possesses the [synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist/) archetype gains his eidolon's hp as temporary hp. On the [Positive Energy Plane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/the-planes/#Positive_Energy_Plane) if a creature's temporary hp exceed its normal hp the creature must succeed on Fortitude saving throws to avoid exploding.

Must a synthesist summoner make such Fortitude saving throws as soon as he's on the Positive Energy Plane?

Comment: how many hp for the summoner, and how many temp hp total on entry?

Comment: A summoner gets d8 health while an Eidolon gains 6+con as health which makes it highly likely for it to exceed the summoners health. If you are asking for a specific character i am not asking because of a character. I am just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, the temporary hit points count against the limit before you need to save against exploding.

Temporary hit points from different sources [stack](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9r43). The major positive-dominant planar trait has no indication that the source of temporary hit points matter, so only the total is taken into account. If the eidolon has more hit points than its master, he will need to save immediately.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a 'No, but...', not a 'yes'?  That is, they do not necessarily need to save, but are more likely to have to do so (i.e. they do so if the eidolon has more hp than the master and they are uninjured, not automatically like is posited in the question)

Answer (score 1):

## By raw, Yes technically. But...

By raw, the source does not matter. Once your Temp HP > Max HP you save or explode.

However, the reason you explode on the positive energy plane is influx of excess life energy.

> However, a creature must make a DC 20 Fortitude save each round that its temporary hit points exceed its normal hit point total

There is nothing that **explicitly** states this cant happen elsewhere, or has to happen on the positive energy plane.  I as a GM would rule ether this applies to other places besides the positive energy plane, or the **source** of the temp HP matters. Whether becoming one with your eidolon counts as holding excess life force is up to GM.

Comment: Do you have any rules text or personal experience that would explain why you'd port the Positive Energy Plane's "fort or die" mechanic to other sources of temporary hit points?

Comment: There arnt too many creatures native to that plane that I could find. But between the wording of the lore around why you explode, and albeit from 3rd party content (Tome of Horrors) The positive energy elemental, who can charge living creatures with extra temp health,  (Which wouldnt be dangerous outside the plane otherwise)

I do not see why a persons body would react to being supercharged with temp health/energy any differently on the positive plane than the material plane, apart from the fact that the positive plane actively charges you. Furthermore it was a possible suggestion of two.

Comment: Counterpoint: it only happens on the Positive Energy Plane because it's so suffused with life energy that there's no where for that energy to "bleed off" where other planes would naturally allow characters' build-up of life energy to to do so. Anecdote: a friend had a Wizard/Rogue stuck in the Positive Energy Plane for a while who knew about the "exploding" thing and needed time to prepare Plane Shift; queue several hours of sneak-attacking themselves to not explode.

Comment: Fair counter point. I dont think ether way is inherently wrong, so much as a matter of  interpretation. I still can see it as possible outside of the positive plane if you take in too much too fast, but the plane makes it far easier as its temp hp doesnt fade until you leave.